# Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIResponder'

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am running into this issue when trying to compile code for an iPhone app that I inherited from a previous developer. I've poked around on a couple forums and it seems like the culprit may be a circular #import somewhere.

First - Is there any easy way to find if this is the case/find what files the loop is in?

Second - Its definitely possible this isn't the problem. This is the full error (truncated file paths so its easier to view here):

In file included

```
      from [...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9,
                 from [...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityIndicatorView.h:8,
                 from [...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11,
                 from /Users/wbs/Documents/EINetIPhone/EINetIPhone_Prefix.pch:13:
[...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:15: error: expected ')' before 'UIResponder'
[...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:17: error: expected '{' before '-' token
[...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:42: warning: '@end' must appear in an @implementation context
[...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:51: error: expected ':' before ';' token
[...]/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:58: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'UIResponder'
```

As you can see, there are other errors alongside this one. These seem to be simple syntax errors, however, they appear in one of Apple's UIKit files (not my own) so I am seriously doubting that Apple's code is truly producing these errors.

I'm stumped as to how to solve this issue. If anyone has any ideas of things I could try or ways/places I could get more info on the problem, I'd really appreciate it. I'm very new to Obj-C and iPhone coding.

Edit:

Just tried Clean All Targets - it actually found an extra warning but still have the same errors as above.

My EINetIPhone_Prefix.pch:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'EINetIPhone' target in the 'EINetIPhone' project
//
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif


#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Edit #2:

Interestingly, I tried removing the UIKit import from my prefix file and putting it into the specific .m files that need it. I still get the same errors, but now they occur in every file attempting to import UIKit.h. Is it possible that UIKit is messed up?

Comment: It looks like you might have a syntax error in EINetIPhone_Prefix.pch, can you post the contents of that file?

Comment: I think so too. Have you done a Clean All Targets?

Comment: See edit for my prefix file. Clean All Targets didn't seem to help :(

Answer (score 0):

Perform a “Clean” (under the “Build” menu) and make sure to check “Also Remove Precompiled Headers”.